# How do I properly pass string data to a numpy record array (and get it out)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large set of data that I need to manipulate with Numpy.  This data set contains strings that I will need for processing downstream.  When I convert the data into a structured array I specified that the data was a string.  I created the record array without any errors, however, when I attempt to convert the data back into a list of nested lists my string data is gone.  Here is an sample....

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [100.0, 400.0, 'stringhere'],
    [200.0, 500.0, 'another sting'],
]

npdata = np.array(map(tuple, data),
                dtype=([('x', 'float64'), ('y', 'float64'), ('label', 'S'), ])
)

for entry in npdata:
    print list(entry)
```

This prints...
[100.0, 400.0, '']
[200.0, 500.0, '0']

I'm new to structured arrays so I'm assuming I either specified my data type incorrectly or I'm misunderstanding how structured arrays deal with strings.  How do I get my string data out of a structured array?

Comment: Numpy arrays have to contain the same type for all elements in the array, so the first 2 float values will be casted.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza that is not true for [recarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the number of bytes in your string dtype. Otherwise, numpy is setting the number of bytes to 1:

```
In [44]: npdata['label'].dtype
Out[44]: dtype('S1')
```

and truncating your data.

So, for example, if you replace `S` with `|S20` then the string dtype will support strings of up to 20 bytes:

```
npdata = np.array(map(tuple, data),
                dtype=([('x', 'float64'), ('y', 'float64'), ('label', '|S20'), ]))

for entry in npdata:
    print list(entry)
```

yields:

```
[100.0, 400.0, 'stringhere']
[200.0, 500.0, 'another sting']
```